# Why does this regular expression match in pcregrep but not within my c++ code?

Tags: c++, regex, pcre, multiline, pcregrep

I have a regex that works perfectly with `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M '([a-zA-Z0-9_&*]+)(\(+)([a-zA-Z0-9_ &\*]+)(\)+)(\n)(\{)'
```

Now I tried to include this regex in my C++ code but it does not match (escapes included):

```
char const *regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9_&*]+)\\(+([a-zA-Z0-9_ &\\*]+)\\)+(?>\n+)\\{+";
re = pcre_compile(regex, PCRE_MULTILINE, &error, &erroffset, 0);
```

I'm trying to find function bodies like this (the paragraph is `0a` in hex):

```
my_function(char *str)
{
```

Why does it work with `pcregrep` and not within the C++ code?

Comment: Which compiler version are you using? Full regex support is available for e.g. GCC 4.9 or newer.

Comment: g++ 4.9.2-10ubuntu13

Comment: I've never seen `(?>\n+)` in a regular expression. What does `?>` mean? Why do you use it in your C++ code but not in pcregrep?

Comment: [The (?> is called an atomic group, which basically means that PCRE will not backtrack if it fails to match it.](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/10/PCRE-and-newlines.html) I could use (\r+) aswell. But (\n+) does not work, though the paragraph is `0a`. There's some problem concerning multiline I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex:

```
 ( [a-zA-Z0-9_&*]+ )           # (1)
 ( \(+ )                       # (2)
 ( [a-zA-Z0-9_ &\*]+ )         # (3)
 ( \)+ )                       # (4)
 ( \n )                        # (5)
 ( \{ )                        # (6)
```

Your second regex:

```
 ( [a-zA-Z0-9_&*]+ )           # (1)
 \(+
 ( [a-zA-Z0-9_ &\*]+ )         # (2)
 \)+
 (?> \n+ )
 \{+
```

Other than different capture groups and an unnecessary atomic group `(?>)`

there is one thing that is obviously different:

The last newline and curly brace in the second regex have `+` quantifiers.
But that's 1 or more, so I think the first regex would be a subset of the second.

The un-obvious difference is that it is unknown if the files were opened in *translated* mode or not.

You can usually cover all cases with `\r?\n` in place of `\n`.
(or even `(?:\r?\n|\r)` ).

So, if you want to quantify the linebreak, it would be `(?:\r?\n)+` or `(?:\r?\n|\r)+`.

The other option might be to try the linebreak construct (I think its `\R`)
instead (available on the newest versions of pcre).

If that doesn't work, it's something else.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! `(?:\r?\n)+` does the job. Thanks!